# CDATA with XSLT does not appear

Tags: xslt, cdata

I have a piece of xml file that has the following information:

```
  <infAdic>
   <infAdFisco>IMUNIDADE ICMS CONF. ART.155 DA CONST. FEDERAL-LUB.     DERIVADO</infAdFisco> 
    <infCpl>
      Preco sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta(ao)      adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de carregamento,     descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de Artigo 22, do Decreto N.96044/88) 
       <![CDATA[ <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega>]]> 
        PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 
    </infCpl>
    <obsCont xCampo="DOCNUM">
      <xTexto>0006703134</xTexto> 
    </obsCont>
    <obsCont xCampo="emailDestinatarioNFe">
      <xTexto>xxxxx@xxxx.com</xTexto> 
    </obsCont>
    <obsCont xCampo="idAplic">
    <xTexto>LUBES</xTexto> 
    </obsCont>
 </infAdic>
```

But when I execute the xml file above with xlst programa below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:nfe="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" cdata-section-elements="nfe:infCpl"/>
<xsl:template match="/nfe:enviNFe">
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap12:Header>
            <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeRecepcao2">
                <cUF>
                    <xsl:value-of select="nfe:NFe[1]/nfe:infNFe/nfe:ide/nfe:cUF"/>
                </cUF>
                <versaoDados>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@versao"/>
                </versaoDados>
            </nfeCabecMsg>
        </soap12:Header>
        <soap12:Body>
            <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeRecepcao2">
                    <enviNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
                        <xsl:attribute name="versao"><xsl:value-of select="@versao"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="nfe:idLote"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="nfe:NFe">
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">]]></xsl:text>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</NFe>]]></xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </enviNFe>
            </nfeDadosMsg>
        </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can not see the infCpl field with CDATA information. 
  This is the result that I see:

```
 <infCpl>
     Preco sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta      (ao) adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de    carregamento,      descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de         Artigo     22, do Decreto N.96044/88) 
    <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega> 
      PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 
 </infCpl>
```

Could you help me because a I want the result below?

```
 <infCpl>
    Preco sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta(ao)      adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de carregamento,     descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de Artigo     22, do Decreto N.96044/88) 
     <![CDATA[ <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega>]]> 
  PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 
 </infCpl>
```

Regards,
Sérgio Salomão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that `infCpl` will only contain CDATA and not mixed content (elements and CDATA), you can specify `infCpl` as a `cdata-section-element` in your `xsl:output`

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="infCpl"/>
```

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<infAdic>
    <infAdFisco>IMUNIDADE ICMS CONF. ART.155 DA CONST. FEDERAL-LUB.     DERIVADO</infAdFisco> 
    <infCpl>
        Preco &amp; &gt; &lt; &apos; &quot; sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta(ao)      adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de carregamento,     descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de Artigo 22, do Decreto N.96044/88) 
        <![CDATA[ <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega>]]> 
        PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 
    </infCpl>
    <obsCont xCampo="DOCNUM">
        <xTexto>0006703134</xTexto> 
    </obsCont>
    <obsCont xCampo="emailDestinatarioNFe">
        <xTexto>xxxxx@xxxx.com</xTexto> 
    </obsCont>
    <obsCont xCampo="idAplic">
        <xTexto>LUBES</xTexto> 
    </obsCont>
</infAdic>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="infCpl"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<infAdic>
   <infAdFisco>IMUNIDADE ICMS CONF. ART.155 DA CONST. FEDERAL-LUB.     DERIVADO</infAdFisco>
   <infCpl><![CDATA[
        Preco & > < ' " sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta(ao)      adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de carregamento,     descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de Artigo 22, do Decreto N.96044/88) 
         <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega> 
        PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 
    ]]></infCpl>
   <obsCont xCampo="DOCNUM">
      <xTexto>0006703134</xTexto>
   </obsCont>
   <obsCont xCampo="emailDestinatarioNFe">
      <xTexto>xxxxx@xxxx.com</xTexto>
   </obsCont>
   <obsCont xCampo="idAplic">
      <xTexto>LUBES</xTexto>
   </obsCont>
</infAdic>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, the infCpl field will have text and CDATA mixed. Could you have another option? Regards,

Comment: @user1916896 - text and CDATA together is fine (they're the same thing really) so my answer should work fine for you. Even entity references like `&amp;` will end up as literal characters (`&`) in the cdata section. (I will update the example.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, if i use the code that you informed I will see the infCpl field like below? <infCpl> Preco sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta(ao) adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de carregamento, descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de Artigo 22, do Decreto N.96044/88) <![CDATA[ <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega>]]> PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 </infCpl>

Comment: @user1916896 - No you will see it like the output in my example. All of the contents of `infCpl` will be wrapped in CDATA, but that's ok and is equivalent to the `infCpl` in your comment.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to see a text and CDATA mixed but not wrapped. I want this result: infCpl> Preco sujeito alteracao. - O(s) produto(s) objeto(s) desta Nota Fiscal esta(ao) adequadamente acondicionado(s) para suportar os riscosnormais de carregamento, descarregamento, transbordo e transporte (Letra C do Item II, de Artigo 22, do Decreto N.96044/88) <![CDATA[ <fabEntrega>Codi</fabEntrega>]]> PO. number: Teste NFe 13122012 </infCpl>  Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

CDATA in XML is not designed to carry information. You shouldn't care about CDATA boundaries in your input. If you do care about them, then you need different tools - XSLT assumes that CDATA is just an authoring convenience, not a way of communicating information to the document recipient.

However, if you're stuck with processing XML in which CDATA has been abused in this way, then you might look at Andrew Welch's LexEv tool, which is bundled in KernowForSaxon.